# stylesheet_pack_tag not generating any output, although the CSS file is present in the packs directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker

With a recent update of Rails, the `stylesheet_pack_tag` of our VueJS client application stopped producing output. Webpacker **does** generate the CSS file in the `/public/packs` folder (next to the JS file and others). The `javascript_pack_tag` statement works fine, but somehow the `stylesheet_pack_tag` remains defunct. What am I possibly overlooking?

Answer (score 8):

Some debugging got me the answer I was looking for. It turns out that previously in the **Webpacker 3.2.0** gem, the `stylesheet_pack_tag` looks like this:

```
def stylesheet_pack_tag(*names, **options)
  unless Webpacker.dev_server.running? && Webpacker.dev_server.hot_module_replacing?
    stylesheet_link_tag(*sources_from_pack_manifest(names, type: :stylesheet), **options)
  end
end
```

In the new **Webpacker 4.0.X** gem, the `stylesheet_pack_tag` looks like this:

```
def stylesheet_pack_tag(*names, **options)
  if current_webpacker_instance.config.extract_css?
    stylesheet_link_tag(*sources_from_manifest_entries(names, type: :stylesheet), **options)
  end
end
```

And right at the start is the culprit: this statement only works when `webpacker.yml` contains `extract_css: true`, like so:

```
default: &default
  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true
```

Of course you can also set this on development, test or production level specifically.

In hindsight, [the Webpacker 3.5 to 4 upgrade docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v4-upgrade.md) already mentioned this change (point 6 in the first paragraph) as well as [in this paragraph](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v4-upgrade.md#upgrading-projects-with-custom-webpack-setups-that-use-only-the-view-helpers).

Comment: Thank you for the research and finding the answer. This is still useful in 2023 :)